# Detecting White ball using iPhone over green grass

Tags: ios, camera

Currently i have task to detect white ball over green grass for that.

1.I took image with green grass and ball.

2.Converted that image into grayscale.

3.Changed brightness and contracts

Comment: GPUImage has a filter in demo app which makes green color go transparent in real time and show background image it works well with camera you can tweak it i don't exactly know the name of filter my colleague showed it to me

Comment: You can put a all black background image so your ball will show white against black that will make identification easy

Comment: Programatically you want to detect ball?

Comment: Thanks to all for reply, @Retro Yes I want to detect the white ball from that image.

Comment: HoughCircles gives false circle along with ball